# SPServices CompleteFunc returns error

Tags: sharepoint-server, spservices, jquery-ajax

I have a problem with getting items using SPServices:

```
<script src="servername/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="servername/SiteAssets/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    checkReservationStatus();
});
     function checkReservationStatus () {
     var weburl = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();
    var list = "listname";
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    webURL: weburl,
    async:false,
    listName: list,
    // get list name from passed variable lisTitle
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Criteria_x0020_Met' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {alert(Status);
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
            status = $(this).attr("ows_Criteria_x0020_Met");
            alert(status);
        })
    }
})
if(status == "Yes") {
    return "Yes";
} else {
    return "No";
}
}  
 </script>
```

the completefunc argument "Status" returns an error and therefore never executes my logic.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

console or alert `xData.responseText` like below,

```
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
                            alert("Response:"+ xData.responseText); 
                            console.log("Response:"+ xData.responseText);
                            ...
    }
```

from the response you can find the error.
Also make sure that following,

- you are referring SP Service correctly [`alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());`]
- Listname & field names are correct. [internal names]

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: then try `alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());` in  `$(document).ready` function

Comment: it returns my site name

Comment: that means SP Services refereed correctly. Now check the list name & field names  given are correct.

Comment: list name is returning correctly. Do I use internal list column name like this Criteria_x0020_Met or use Display name in FieldRed Name="<column name>"??

Comment: Here's my caml 

CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Criteria_x0020_Met' /></ViewFields>"

Comment: Use internal field names & try with `ID` field only in `CAMLViewFields`.Also check this link -https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/crud-operation-on-list-in-sharepoint-using-jquery-and-spservices

Comment: I had a look on link you sent me. it looks like my code. the problem is when my code gets to that completefunc(xData, Status){
it doesn't get here
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){alert(xData.responseXML);
status = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
   alert(status);
it diesn't get here.
})
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test code which works fine, you could try it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            checkReservationStatus();
        });
        function checkReservationStatus() {
            var weburl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            var list = "MyData1";
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                webURL: weburl,
                async: false,
                listName: list,
                // get list name from passed variable lisTitle
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Criteria_x0020_Met' /></ViewFields>",
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    alert(Status);
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                        status = $(this).attr("ows_Criteria_x0020_Met");
                        alert(status);
                    })
                }
            })
            if (status == "Yes") {
                return "Yes";
            } else {
                return "No";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried it but still the Status parameter returns error and the doesn't hit out conditions.

Comment: Insert a breakpoint to completefunc and monitor the detailed error info in xData.

Comment: I managed to fix it. look at the following code: SP was parsing special characters that were causing issues. I'm sorted now. 


var specialCharsDeleted = xData.responseText.replace(/&#11;/g, '');
     var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( specialCharsDeleted );
                    $(xmlDoc).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                        status = $(this).attr("ows_Criteria_x0020_Met");

});